# dynamically changing html within a group of li tags

Tags: jquery, each

I am trying to change the `<li>` html within a each loop but all the LI elements are displaying the same image source. If you take a look at this Fiddle, you will see what i mean.

(http://jsfiddle.net/dxhqL/2/)

I wasnt able to submit just the jsfiddle url so i included the code here as well.
here is the html:

```
<ul class="gallery-thumbnail">
<li><img width="68" height="68" src="http://leandrovieira.com/projects/jquery/lightbox/photos/image1.jpg"></li>
<li><img width="68" height="68" src="http://leandrovieira.com/projects/jquery/lightbox/photos/image2.jpg"></li>
<li><img width="68" height="68" src="http://leandrovieira.com/projects/jquery/lightbox/photos/image3.jpg"></li>
<li><img width="68" height="68" src="http://leandrovieira.com/projects/jquery/lightbox/photos/image4.jpg"></li>
</ul>
```

Here is the JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("ul.gallery-thumbnail li img").each(function() {
        $("ul.gallery-thumbnail li").html("<a href='" + $(this).attr("src") + "'><img width='68' height='68' src='" + $(this).attr("src") + "'></a>");
    }); 
});
```

Comment: `$("ul.gallery-thumbnail li")` selects all `li` elements. If you want to current `img` element, use `this` and traverse the tree up with `.parent`. Have a look at the documentation: http://api.jquery.com/each/, http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/tree-traversal/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to select the right image.  Use `.eq` with the very handy index passed into the `.each` callback:

```
$("ul.gallery-thumbnail li img").each(function(idx) {
    $("ul.gallery-thumbnail li").eq(idx).html("<a href='" + $(this).attr("src") + "'><img width='68' height='68' src='" + $(this).attr("src") + "'></a>");
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ExplosionPIlls/dxhqL/3/

Comment: `$(this).parent()` or `$(this).closest('li')` would be much cleaner solution. At least don't select the `li` elements inside the callback over and over again.

Comment: thank you explosion. Your method worked i'll have to look into eq() and what felix mentioned. :)

Comment: @FelixKling is saying that calling `$("ul.gallery-thumbnail li")` is less efficient than storing it in a variable or just using `$(this).parent()`

Answer (score 2):

You could use [.wrap()](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/) here

```
$("ul.gallery-thumbnail li img").each(function () {
    $(this).wrap("<a href=\"" + this.src + "\" />");
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dxhqL/4/

Comment: Good idea. Can be simplified to `$("ul.gallery-thumbnail li img").wrap(function() { return "<a href=\"" + this.src + "\" />";});`.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $(this).closest('li').html("<a href='" + $(this).attr("src") + "'><img width='68' height='68' src='" + $(this).attr("src") + "'></a>");

get the closest <li>  and it will work
```

Answer (score -2):

```
    $(document).ready(function() {

    $("ul.gallery-thumbnail li img") {
        $("ul.gallery-thumbnail li").html("<a href='" + $(this).attr("src") + "'><img width='68' height='68' src='" + $(this).attr("src") + "'></a>");

    }); 
});
```

You might want to delete `.each(function()` Hope this helps.

Comment: What is `$("ul.gallery-thumbnail li img") { ... });` supposed to do? Your code is full of syntax errors.

Comment: thanks, but your method wouldnt work since each needs to go from each one as an array. I didnt know you can set it up as a function like that, how would you use that?